# Fast Perl<->Python serialization that supports integer dictionary keys

Tags: python, perl, serialization, dictionary

I'm looking for a **fast** (xml is way too slow) serialization method that could be used in both Perl and Python.

Unfortunately, I can't use JSON (and many others) because it always changes type of a dict key from integer to a string. I need serialization/deserialization that preserves key type.

Python:

```
>>> import json
>>> dict_before = {1:'one', 20: 'twenty'}
>>> data = json.dumps(dict_before)
>>> dict_after = json.loads(data)

>>> dict_before
{1: 'one', 20: 'twenty'}            #integer keys
>>> dict_after
{u'1': u'one', u'20': u'twenty'}    #string keys
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/). Its compact and fast. There is a [perl implementation](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-perl) but I've never used it. The python impl works though:

```
>>> import msgpack
>>> x=msgpack.dumps({1:'aaa',2:'bbb'})
>>> x
'\x82\x01\xa3aaa\x02\xa3bbb'
>>> len(x)
11
>>> print msgpack.loads(x)
{1: 'aaa', 2: 'bbb'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use yaml.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> dict_before = {1:'one', 20: 'twenty'}
>>> data = yaml.safe_dump(dict_before)
>>> dict_after = yaml.safe_load(data)
>>> dict_after
{1: 'one', 20: 'twenty'}
```

I had similar problem. I wanted to share a configuration file in Perl and Python and I had to use yaml.

You can install yaml module in python with:

```
pip install PyYAML
```

Although, integer keys will be converted to string in perl => [Legal values for Perl hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719428/legal-values-for-perl-hash-key)

Comment: Thank You. The problem is: I have to serialize a LOT of complex data, so efficiency is extremely important. Simplejson have serialized my test data in 0.2s, Yaml in... 66.2s! Too slow for my case.

Comment: @cimak That was resolved recently => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404441/why-is-pyyaml-spending-so-much-time-in-just-parsing-a-yaml-file

Answer (score 2):

Mu. You have started with the wrong premise.

Perl does not have a meaningful type system that distinguishes between numbers and strings. Any given value can be *both*. It can't be determined using only the Perl language whether a given value is considered to be a number only (although you can use modules like `Devel::Peek`). It is utterly impossible to know what type a given value *originally* was.

```
my $x = 1;     # an integer (IV), right?
say "x = $x";  # not any more! It's a PVIV now (string and integer)
```

Furthermore, in a hash map (“dictionary”), the key type is *always* coerced to a string. In arrays, the key is *always* coerced to an integer. Other types can only be faked.

This is wonderful when parsing text, but of course introduces endless pain when serializing a data structure. JSON maps perfectly to Perl data structures, so I suggest you stick to that (or YAML, as it is a superset of JSON) to protect yourself from the delusion that a serialization could infer information that isn't possibly there.

What do we take from this?

- If interop is important, refrain from using creative dictionary types in Python.
- You can always encode type information in the serialization should it really be important (hint: it probably isn't): `{"type":"interger dict", "data":{"1":"foo","2":"bar"}}`
- It would also be premature to dismiss XML as too slow. See [this recent article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/08/xml-json-performance), although I disagree with the methods, and it restricts itself to JS (last week's [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6217170) for perspective).

  If it is native, it will probably be fast enough, so obviously don't use any pure-Perl or pure-Python implementations. This also holds for JSON- and YAML- and whatnot -parsers.