# Why is PyYAML spending so much time in just parsing a YAML File?

Tags: python, json, yaml, pyyaml

I am parsing a YAML file with around 6500 lines with this format:

```
foo1:
  bar1:
    blah: { name: "john", age: 123 }
  metadata: { whatever1: "whatever", whatever2: "whatever" }
  stuff:
    thing1: 
      bluh1: { name: "Doe1", age: 123 }
      bluh2: { name: "Doe2", age: 123 }
    thing2:
    ...
    thingN:
foo2:
...
fooN:
```

I just want to parse it with the [PyYAML library](http://pyyaml.org/) (I think there is no more alternatives to it in Python: [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/best-way-to-parse-a-yaml-file)).

Just for testing, I write that code to parse my file:

```
import yaml

config_file = "/path/to/file.yaml"

stream = open(config_file, "r")
sensors = yaml.load(stream)
```

Executing the script with `time` command along with the script I get this time:

```
real    0m3.906s
user    0m3.672s
sys     0m0.100s
```

That values doesn't seem too good really. I just want to test the same with JSON, just converting the same YAML file to JSON first:

```
import json

config_file = "/path/to/file.json"

stream = open(config_file, "r")
sensors = json.load(stream)  # We read the yaml config file
```

But the execution time is far better:

```
real    0m0.058s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.008s
```

**Why is the main reason that PyYAML spends more time parsing the YAML file than parsing the JSON one?** Is it a problem of PyYAML or is it because of the YAML format is hard to parse? *(probably is the first one)*

**EDIT:**

I add another example with ruby and YAML:

```
require 'yaml'

sensors = YAML.load_file('/path/to/file.yaml')
```

And the execution time is good! (or at least not as bad as the PyYAML example):

```
real    0m0.278s
user    0m0.240s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Comment: Similar question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451732/how-is-it-that-json-serialization-is-so-much-faster-than-yaml-serialization-in-p

Comment: @moliware Yes, I read that one before. But the question was about serialization, and the answers don't seem to answer my question :(

Comment: After your edit I understand. Did you install it with the proper option: $ python setup.py --with-libyaml install

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions here: http://rmcgibbo.github.io/blog/2013/05/23/faster-yaml-parsing-with-libyaml/ but LibYAML didn't improve anything.

Comment: Can you post a link to the yaml and json data files you are using. I want to compare the two and see where the time is being spent.

Comment: I have to prepare a new one because the one that I am using contains sensitive data :(

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh http://tny.cz/34e8b128

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) you must use `CLoader`/`CSafeLoader` (and `CDumper`):

```
import yaml
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader

config_file = "test.yaml"

stream = open(config_file, "r")
sensors = yaml.load(stream, Loader=Loader)
```

This gives me

```
real    0m0.503s
```

instead of

```
real    0m2.714s
```